# Is there a way like Promise.all() in RxJava?

Tags: java, android, rx-java

I have a question.

I need to get list of some items by a list of the item ids.
At first, I tried

```
Observable.from(itemIds)
  .flatMap(itemId -> requestToServer(itemId))
  .subscribe(item -> { /* do something */ });
```

But the operator `flatMap` does not guarantee the order of items. 
I need to get item in order that `ItemIds` have.

It would be great if there was the api like `Promise.all()`. 
Is there a way like `Promise.all()` in RxJava? or any other ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [concatMap](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#concatMap(rx.functions.Func1)) instead. That will concatenate the emitted Observables in order rather than merging their emissions

> Returns a new Observable that emits items resulting from applying a
>   function that you supply to each item emitted by the source
>   Observable, where that function returns an Observable, and then
>   emitting the items that result from concatinating those resulting
>   Observables.

Comment: Yes, but `concatMap` processes the request one by one. 
What I want to do is that all requests are concurrent, but all responses are in order. as `Promise.all()` do.

Comment: Perhaps this article will help? Haven't tried this trick w/ `concatMap` though, so not sure: http://tomstechnicalblog.blogspot.com/2015/11/rxjava-achieving-parallelization.html

Comment: I found `concatMapEager` operator. This is what I need, maybe. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

It sounds like you're looking for the [Zip operator](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#zip%28rx.Observable,%20rx.functions.FuncN%29)

For example:

```
Observable<Integer> obs1 = Observable.just(1);
Observable<String> obs2 = Observable.just("Blah");
Observable<Boolean> obs3 = Observable.just(true);

Observable.zip(obs1, obs2, obs3, (Integer i, String s, Boolean b) -> i + " " + s + " " + b)
 .subscribe(str -> System.out.println(str));
```

prints:

`1 Blah true`