# Waiting for all results before returning Android

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, promise

I have a little issues, I have make a request to my database (Firebase) to get a set of ids, these ids are live inside a subcollection. When these ids are returned, I will use these ids to get the objects they correspond to. Here is my code

```
List<DocumentSnapshot> temp = input.getDocuments();
for (DocumentSnapshot snapshot: temp) {
     String journeyId = snapshot.get("id").toString();
     //make another request to database
     //get the result and add to returnobject
}            
return returnObject;
```

Where input is of type QuerySnapshot. I would really like to not return the returnObject till all the objects have been returned from the database. I have a background with Promises in node and using Promise.map is there an equivalent in Android?

Comment: With RxJava you can achieve this. Have look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35348279/3331710

Comment: @mark922 That would solve my issue. Thanks a lot for the suggestion!